# H264 decode always latency one frame

Tags: h.264, encoder, decoder, vaapi

Encoder encode a video (IDR P P P ...) and send to decoder and display it in real time, and I noticed encoder send i th frame but decoder display i-1 th frame.

I know p frame need to be removed from ref list so it can be removed from decode picture buffer, but it would cause next p frame decode fails.

Is there way to fix one frame delay?

Becase one frame delay is about 33 ms latency as 30fps, which is unacceptable.

Comment: If you want a lower delay an intra frame codec is probably best

Answer (score 0):

When you use 30 fps, the time budget for each frame, be it I or be it P, is 33ms. To encode, transmit, and decode a frame cannot possibly take less than 33ms. It probably takes more than that, even twice that.

If you need less latency, increase the frame rate.